# mongodb repair/compact/index infinite like behaviour

Tags: mongodb, indexing, repair

From the start,

I have a collection with about 51m records. So I indexed one of the fields when the percent progress started to increase above 100% (800% complete) so I cancelled this and figured I must have some db corruption

So I did a validation of the collections and found they were ok. Nonetheless I tried a compact and a repair and I find that in the temp folder (for a repair) or my db folder for a compact

I used to have 'collection.0' to 'collection.14' but checking it after 14 hours I found it counting to 'collection.64' and had to cancel it. Its highly unusual from my previous experiences that this is normal behaviour.

Previously the database size was 20 gig and during this compact it increased to well over 100gb due to this

What could be wrong and how would I fix my database?

From the console each one will have

```
Allocating new datafile ... Size: 2047MB, took 107 seconds
```

(For each of the 15 to 64 additional files)

Comment: was anything else running when you were originally creating the index (i.e. anything inserting more data in?) did you create index with backround:true? what version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: Nothing else was running (I started it and performed this as the only task). Im using the Mac version `2.0.4`

Comment: I've tried it again with the latest nightly and the same thing its indexing more documents that I have. I'm not sure if this is normal or a bug

Comment: Are you running on the nightly builds? This is going to be really hard to debug as no one should be running on those. Check the Google Groups and mention your issue there, you may have found a bug.

Comment: Are you saying that the compact grew your database from 20 to 100 gb? A more compact doesn't reduce the size of your database, it makes the data more dense, i.e. helps reduce fragmentation. Or more logically, are you saying that the index grew your database? If so, that will logically happen & it's not free but I'm very surprised at the huge increase in size as a result of creating an index. Can you share further details? The 800% bit would appear to be a bug and you should file one in http://jira.mongodb.org.

Comment: The index didn't cause the dramatic increase in size, Its just another characteristic I noticed: it overindexes. But the compact itself increased the size, I'm fairly certain its a bug. I mentioned it in the mongodb-user group and awaiting a response there

Comment: Yep, I see it on GG....I'll ask my questions there. Compact rebuilds the indexes so that could be one thing.